# Are OpenTok stream video dimensions reversed?

Tags: ios, stream, frame, webrtc, opentok

I'm developing an app using ***OpenTok*** for iPad/iPhone. When a device is in **portrait**, `user.stream.videoDimensions.width` gives **640** and `user.stream.videoDimensions.height` gives **480**, while it should be **480** and **640** respectively.

When a device is in **landscape**, `user.stream.videoDimensions.width` gives **480** and `user.stream.videoDimensions.height` gives **640**, while it should be **640** and **480** respectively.

I have to correct the dimensions of the video view's frame size by swapping the width and height as follows:

```
CGSize userVideoFrameSize = user.stream.videoDimensions;
CGSize userCorrectVideoFrameSize = CGSizeMake(userVideoFrame.height, userVideoFrame.width);
```

`user` may be an `OTPublisher/OTPublisherKit` or `OTSubscriber/OTSubscriberKit`.

Is this a bug in the ***OpenTok*** framework or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Again, I'll ask, where is the stream being published from? (I don't understand why my comments were deleted, I'm trying to help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes, the video dimensions were reversed. But it has been fixed in 2.6.0.

Initially, when I contacted OpenTok developers about the problem, they did not accept it as a bug and said that the dimensions were correct and I was doing something wrong in my code. Well, I swapped the dimensions in my code to temporarily fix the problem for myself. In the next release of OpenTok, they fixed the issue.

There was another problem with letter-boxing, I reported it to them, and they didn't accept it as a bug, and said that everything is working fine. But then they fixed it in the same release.

Answer (score 2):

They say that this issue has been fixed in OpenTok iOS SDK 2.6.0.

Please check out release notes:
https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/release-notes.html

[image]